# Is asking for the criterion and consequences of an algorithm choice considered too broad?

Tags: discussion

I would like to put forward a question to the effect of "*What are the criterion for choosing Forward Shading vs. Deferred Shading and what are their consequences e.g.: Deferred shading makes many light sources cheaper but makes transparency difficult and eats up VRAM.*"

Does this seem too broad to the point that it becomes off topic for off-loading too much research unto the community?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, it looks like the question is basically

- "What are the criteria for choosing *technology X* versus *technology Y*?"
- "What are the consequences of choosing *technology X* over *technology Y*?

both of which sound like basic "which technology" questions to me (which means they're off topic).

Comment: Thanks Josh, do you think there is a good way to ask for the objective consequences (not stating consequences as a subjective pros/cons thing, but just what does it enable/disable someone from doing with their renderer) when using Deferred Shading? Or does that still sound too broad and offloading research for GameDev SE?

Comment: I think that is harder to judge on the surface, without seeing the actual questions.